# Stuck with Parsing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Using VS2010 Express, C# and it's WinForms Application.

Here I have three text boxes(aTextBox, bTextBox, cTextBox) from which Inputs are strings and then using int.Parse(aTextBox.Text) converted to integers.

Then a Button (calcBtn) method which is going to calculate charges and then to display results after some maths to particular TextBoxes on Result groupBox which again contains text boxes for results...

The problem is causing by the way I am parsing or the order in which it's executing. If any of the textbox is filled then result should display and not to get in the format exceptions. Here I am getting stuck because inside the calcBtn I am parsing all text boxes and if one of them is empty then exception occurs. Compiler is I guess trying to parse empty strings from the empty text boxes, and I don't want it to be.

Any suggestions if you got what I mean? :)

Here's what GUI looks like
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Int32.Parse` method does not accept malformed strings, and this includes empty strings.  I have two suggestions.

You could check if the string is empty/whitespace first, and return 0 or some other default value:

```
private static int ParseInteger(string str)
{
    if (str == null || str.Trim() == "")
        return 0;

    // On .NET 4 you could use this instead.  Prior .NET versions do not
    // have the IsNullOrWhiteSpace method.
    //
    // if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
    //    return 0;

    return Int32.Parse(str);
}
```

Or you could simply ignore all parsing errors, treating them as 0.  This will treat things like `""`, `"123abc"`, and `"foobar"` as zero.

```
private static int ParseInteger(string str)
{
    int value;
    if (Int32.TryParse(str, out value))
        return value;

    return 0;
}
```

Which approach you take depends on the specific needs of your application.

Comment: any possibility without having the decision statements?

Comment: @Jasmine Appelblad Why wouldn't you want to use if statements?

Comment: @Odnxe this is an exercise from lecture notes which do not contain decisions topics and also a requirement for my lecturer.

Comment: Strange requirement. However, you could just use int.Parse in a try block and put your default value in the catch. It's ugly, but it doesn't involve conditional logic.

Comment: no not even the switches :) no decisions. The name of this handout is "Vars, Constants and Calculations".

Comment: Is this an intro class? B/c I can't see a professor, in their right mind, docking you points for using some decision logic. It sounds like he is going to lead into decision logic on his next lecture by showing you what happens if you insert nothing into a text box.

Comment: You cannot handle the empty-string case without *some* kind of conditional, whether it be an `if` block or the ternary (`?:`) operator.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the extended method...

1) method

```
public static class TE
{
    public static int StringToInt(this string x)
    {
        int result;
        return int.TryParse(x, out result) ? result : 0;
    }
}
```

2) use

```
 System.Windows.Forms.TextBox t = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
 int x = t.Text.StringToInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
private static int ParseInteger(string str)
{
    int value;
    Int32.TryParse(str, out value);
    return value;
}
```

without any if, since TryParse set value to 0 if it fails